# python - simulate sys.argv when calling script as function without modifying it

Tags: python

I have an existing script that uses this structure

```
def main():
    import argparse
    cmd_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A tool to work with MicroPython .mpy files.')
    cmd_parser.add_argument('-d', '--dump', action='store_true',
        help='dump contents of files')
    cmd_parser.add_argument('-f', '--freeze', action='store_true',
        help='freeze files')
    cmd_parser.add_argument('-q', '--qstr-header',
        help='qstr header file to freeze against')
    cmd_parser.add_argument('-mlongint-impl', choices=['none', 'longlong', 'mpz'], default='mpz',
        help='long-int implementation used by target (default mpz)')
    cmd_parser.add_argument('-mmpz-dig-size', metavar='N', type=int, default=16,
        help='mpz digit size used by target (default 16)')
    cmd_parser.add_argument('files', nargs='+',
        help='input .mpy files')
    args = cmd_parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Normally, I've been calling it via command line but I plan on `import`ing this script and calling it thus: `theScript.main()`.

The issue is that (I don't think) `sys.argv` will be what this function expects; `sys.argv` will be set to the calling script's values.

What is the most Pythonic way to simulate me calling `theScript` from another script but as if it is being called from the command line?

Should I just manually modify `sys.argv` before calling `theScript.main()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

don't change `sys.argv`. `parse_args` takes `sys.argv[1:]` by default, but you can pass other arguments if you want allowing to call `main` from another python module.

```
def main(args):
    import argparse
    ...
    args = cmd_parser.parse_args(args)

main(["-d","-f"])
```